# Update character set for special characters Oracle Database 12c

Tags: database, oracle12c

I'm looking for a way to update the character set so that it accepts special characters like ñ, tíldes, etc ...
I already have the database imported, it is an Oracle 12c database, and all the special characters are "broken (¿)".

Is there any way I can solve this problem?
Thanks

Image example

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhaGv.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011) is what you need.

Basically, there are two ways to do that:

- Database Migration Assistant for Unicode (it is a GUI tool)
- Full Export and Import

Read the document and pick an option which suits you best. Good luck!